# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When I use

```
WHERE id_prekes = :prekes_id
AND tiekejas = :tiekejas
```

**$prekes_id = 3;**

**$tiekejas = Silberauto, UAB;**

I'm getting error(SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number), but when I'm using

```
WHERE id_prekes = 3
AND tiekejas = "Silberauto, UAB"
```

the error is gone. My script:

```
<?php
$tiekejas = $_GET['tiekejas'];
$prekes_id = $_GET['prekes_id'];

echo // "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$tiekejas');</script>";

$username='root';
$password='pass';
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=univer', $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT vnt_kaina
FROM tiekeju_prekes
INNER JOIN tiekejai ON tiekeju_prekes.id_tiekejo = tiekejai.id
WHERE id_prekes = :prekes_id
AND tiekejas = :tiekejas
                ');

$stmt->bindParam(':tiekejas', $tiekejas, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':prekes_id', $prekes_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $stmt->execute(array('tiekejas' => $tiekejas,'prekes_id' => $prekes_id));

    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        echo $row['vnt_kaina']." LT ";
    }  
} catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo 'KLAIDA: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: And what is there in `$tiekejas` and `$prekes_id`? `echo` them.

Comment: $tiekejas = Silberauto, UAB
$prekes_id = 3;

Comment: Most likely because of the `PARAM_INT` in `$stmt->bindParam(':tiekejas', $tiekejas, PDO::PARAM_INT);` try using `$stmt->bindParam(':tiekejas', $tiekejas, PDO::PARAM_STR);` since you're dealing with strings `"Silberauto, UAB"` @shizaa See the manual http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: THANK YOU! I was looking for it 5 days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use either:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':tiekejas', $tiekejas, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':prekes_id', $prekes_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Or

```
$stmt->execute(array('tiekejas' => $tiekejas,'prekes_id' => $prekes_id));
```

Also pay attention to the `PDO::PARAM_` - `$tiekejas` is a string , so you should use `PDO::PARAM_STR` not `PDO::PARAM_INT`.